# Which glue is good for transparent ABS plastic and easy removal?

Tags: adhesive, abs

Hello all I need to glue some ABS plastic parts together some of them are transparent.

I used AA glue before but it will make my transparent parts foggy and after sticking them together its nearly impossible to disassembly.

So is there a better option than the AA 502 glue for easier removal and not fog my transparent parts?
Thank you

Comment: "good" and "easy removal" are likely to be mutually exclusive...

Comment: You might try clear silicone RTV. Can get it at any hardware store.

Answer (score 1):

You can try ARclear optically transparent adhesives made by Adhesives Research Inc No guarantees though, you will have to experiment to get what you want, of course. :-)

Comment: Adhesive Research makes tapes and transfer adhesives, not liquid glues. Might not be what the OP is looking for. I would have suggested clear silicone RTV.

Comment: The OP said he wanted the adhesive to be strong , removable, and optically transparent, exactly the kinds of adhesives the company makes What did I miss???

Comment: The OP didn't actually specify strong. I have experience with Adhesives Research. They mostly make tape. I think the OP is looking for a liquid adhesive to glue the PVC.

Comment: Maybe the OP can weigh in here and be more specific about what he/she wants

Comment: Thank you very much for all your helps.

I am looking for liquid adhesive or glue to stick the body of my R/C model car that made by ABS plastic also some light covers are transparent so I want a adhesive that will not made the transparent parts foggy.
This doesn't need as strong as AA glue as the body is just for 'decorate' not running parts.

After I asked this question I have tried AB glue and it seems fit my needs for now it's removable but I haven't tried the transparent parts yet

Answer (score 0):

I can't say this will work for sure, but you should try clear silicone RTV. There are any number of companies that make the stuff, like [this](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Permatex-3-oz-Clear-Silicone-Adhesive-Sealant-75151/302775054) for example. Silicone RTV is rubber like and fairly think viscosity. As caulking, it is possible to peel off once cured. You should be able to buy clear silicone RTV at any hardware or home improvement store.